# How to handle very frequent updates to a Lucene index

Tags: asp.net, indexing, lucene, search-engine, lucene.net

Am using Lucene.net 3.0 in my Application which as frequent updates to index.
But when new data on a forum it's not available in the search . it's taking few minutes to update index.
how can i overcome this.....

Comment: Lucene.NET 3.0? Where'd you get that from?

Comment: yes, please share with where you got that, I'm very interested as well!

Answer (score 1):

try this
http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/NearRealtimeSearch